# How to install Adafruit motorshield library in arduino-cli

Tags: library, adafruit, arduino-cli

I need to install [this library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Motor_Shield_V2_Library) using the [arduino-cli](https://www.arduino.cc/pro/cli) software. I don't know what name to use for the library. Using

```
arduino-cli lib install <library_name>
```

I have tried `Adafruit_MotorShield`, `Adafruit_MotorShield_V2`, and other random combinations and in all cases it cannot found it. In the library manager of the graphical interface it is this one:

[image]

Comment: check the name in library.properties

Comment: How do I find the properties of a library?

Comment: I found it on GitHub over arduinolibraries.info and it is in the library's folder too if you have it installed elsewhere. And the More Info link in IDE Library Manager goes to GitHub too

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/adafruit-motor-shield-v2-library)? Where is the name to use?

Comment: Thanks, now I found the [`library.properties`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Motor_Shield_V2_Library/blob/master/library.properties) file.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Juraj♦ in the comments, the name to use can be found in the [`library.properties`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Motor_Shield_V2_Library/blob/master/library.properties) file. There we find `name=Adafruit Motor Shield V2 Library` so the command to install the library is:

```
arduino-cli lib install Adafruit\ Motor\ Shield\ V2\ Library
```

Note the white spaces are escaped.

Comment: quotes didn't work?

Comment: Don't know, I tried at once with that command, which worked.